# Diff/compare two files in Notepad++ launched from command line

Tags: notepad++

How can I launch Notepad++ from the command-line, providing two files and have it open with a diff/compare?

Comment: NppCompareLoader: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20170541/running-notepad-from-command-line-with-compare-plugin-showing-compare-result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/forums/forum/730527/topic/3358936

It doesn't look like Notepad++ has a way of instrumenting plugins from the command line. Since compare is a plugin, it doesn't seem like this is possible.