# Running NotePad++ from Command line with Compare Plugin showing compare result

Tags: compare, notepad++, string-comparison

I am trying to find a way to call notepad++ from command line with compare plugin showing the compare result providing I pass 2 files name which I want to compare.

Think like I have a batch file, which does some work and result is opening notepad++ showing 2 files in compare mode. (Yes, compare plugin is installed)

If anyone has any other suggestion to using any other editor or software also welcome..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543046/how-to-use-diff-and-patch-in-cygwin-on-windows

Answer (score 9):

tl;dr:

The command is `Notepad++\plugins\ComparePlugin\compare.exe file1 file2`.

Details:

Download the compare plugin https://bitbucket.org/uph0/compare/downloads/ComparePlugin.v1.5.6.6.bin.zip. Installing the compare plugin from the plugin manager within Notepad++ does *not* install the requisite exe. I assume you could also build from source to obtain the exe.

Follow the manual installation instructions in the readme:

> To install manually, copy ComparePlugin.dll and ComparePlugin subfolder
>   into the plugins directory C:\Program Files\Notepad++\Plugins.

For a portable Notepad++ installation, you need to run the command from **a directory above the notepad++ directory (or with absolute path of exe)**, otherwise you get an error that Notepad++.exe is not found.

The commands look like this:

```
>cd C:\portapps\Notepad++
>cd ..
>Notepad++\plugins\ComparePlugin\compare.exe C:\files\file1.txt C:\files\file2.txt
```

ufo's answer put me on the right track but it did not contain the commands to run.

Comment: To anyone using Notepad 64bit version: The plugin in link above can't be used. `Cannot load 32-bit plugin. ComparePlugin.dll is not compatible with the current version of Notepad++.`. I had no luck finding any updated version. If you are desperate enough to make it work: 1. Install latest compare plugin via plugin manager/plugins admin. 2. Build [this](https://bitbucket.org/uph0/compare/src/master/loader/) project to get your `compare.exe` (old ones won't work).

Comment: @taz I followed your answer and installed `compare exe` manually. When run `Notepad++\plugins\ComparePlugin\compare.exe C:\files\file1.txt C:\files\file2.txt` from command line it is opening files but not in diff mode. I am using `Notepad++ version 8.1.9.2` my python code is `import subprocess
subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\plugins\ComparePlugin\ComparePlugin\compare.exe", "1.xml", "2.xml"])` python code also opening files but not showing differences by default

Comment: @newsha let me know the steps to build project to get `compare exe`

Answer (score 8):

<del>There's a tool called [NppCompareLoader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sourcecookifier/files/other%20plugins/NppCompareLoader.v0.1.zip/download) doing exactly what you want. Simply drop it in the N++ installation folder. I'm using it since many years as a diff viewer for TortoiseSVN and TortoiseGit, thus you should certainly be able to call it right from command line.</del>

**/EDIT**

Since the (unofficial) [Compare-plug-in version 1.5.6.6](https://bitbucket.org/uph0/compare/downloads/ComparePlugin.v1.5.6.6.bin.zip) the additional loader mentioned above isn't required anymore. There's already one included in the plug-in. Here's the regarding change-log fragment:

- NEW: Loader for using N++ as an external diff viewer (e.g. in TortoiseSVN, TortoiseGit, ..)

Comment: It isn't the correct answer as it does not specify how to call from the command line.

Comment: so what's the answer?

Comment: Just as a hint, if you have special characters in your files, check if both files in compare mode have the same encoding set.