# Can Version Control Recognize Lines Being Transposed?

Tags: git, svn, version-control, diff

Basically, just what's in the title, e.g., if my original file says...

```
Read me!
Lese meg!
¡Leéme!
```

and I commit a version that says...

```
Lese meg!
Read me!
¡Leéme!
```

Is there any version control platform that can recognize that one row has been moved when a diff is done, rather than the following...

```
+Lese meg!
Read me!
-Lese meg!
¡Leéme!
```

I've seen that Notepad++ knows how to do this, but can Git or SVN or something else do it?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10066129/is-there-a-diff-like-algorithm-that-handles-moving-block-of-lines and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590947/using-git-diff-to-detect-code-movement-how-to-use-diff-options

Comment: since you say notepad++ can do this you can use it as a diff viewer, accorging to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27584723/2303202) answer it's possible